# Kafka-streams: windows retention period memory/performance impact

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We have a development in kafka-streams which produces a time window aggregation kind of:

```
selectKey().groupByKey().aggregate()
```

and then using

```
TimeWindows.of().until()
```

My main question is what happens if `until` is not used, let's imagine that we have 1 minute windows and for some unforeseen reason a new event arrives from 1 week ago, does the application save all the windows state from the beginning?, wouldn't it produce an excessive consumption of memory or, in case of persisting the state of all the windows, wouldn't it suppose a significant delay to recover the appropriate window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced the same question recently. The answer can be found in this source file for kafka streams:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Windows.java

Which contains:

```
static final long DEFAULT_MAINTAIN_DURATION_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L; // one day
```

So without specifying an `until()` setting, your windowed state store will keep records for (a lower bound of) one day, by default.

The other part of your question is: what happens to events that arrive late, past the time when the window has been expired?  That answer is in the developer guide:

> In the Kafka Streams DSL users can specify a retention period for the
>   window. This allows Kafka Streams to retain old window buckets for a
>   period of time in order to wait for the late arrival of records whose
>   timestamps fall within the window interval. If a record arrives after
>   the retention period has passed, the record cannot be processed and is
>   dropped.

Piecing that information together shows that if you don't specify an `until()` setting on your windowed stream, the records will be kept for at least one day, and records arriving more than one day late will be dropped.

Comment: "I think that the documentation should be more clear" -- we are always eager to improve the docs. Would you like contribute a PR to improve the web page docs and/or the JavaDocs?

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the comment about the documentation. I was going to take you up on your offer to submit a PR with the default values, and then found the relevant settings already listed in the online docs and the javadoc...  exactly where I would put them...  Not sure why I didn't see them in the first place! Anyways, apologies for the comment, I take it back. :D

Comment: I am not sure about "If a record arrives after the retention period has passed, the record ... is dropped", I have a retention period of 15 minutes and when booting up after several hours off, stream is aggregating records from some hours ago. ¿?